# chmod not working correctly in Dockerfile RUN command. Appears correct during build but it doesn't seem to stick

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Using the following dockerfile, I'm trying to create a folder which is writable for PHP.

```
FROM trafex/alpine-nginx-php7:1.2.0

# Add mysql pdo extensions
USER root
RUN apk add php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql

COPY --chown=nobody:nobody nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody public_html/  /var/www/html

RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/public/ifpos/hits && ls -l /var/www/html/public/ifpos/

USER nobody
```

During the build this is what I see

```
Step 6/7 : RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/public/ifpos/hits && ls -l /var/www/html/public/ifpos/
 ---> Running in 027345f34fc9
total 8
drwxrwxrwx    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Jan 17 04:21 hits
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody         817 Jan 17 03:04 listener.php
```

However when I terminal into the container and list the directory, I can see this hasn't been set correctly.

```
/var/www/html/public/ifpos $ ls -l
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Jan 17 04:21 hits
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody         817 Jan 17 03:04 listener.php
```

Please help, this is doing my head in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `/var/www/html` is marked as `VOLUME` in `trafex/alpine-nginx-php7:1.2.0` image - https://hub.docker.com/r/trafex/alpine-nginx-php7/dockerfile

You can run the `chmod` as part of entrypoint script which does the `chmod` first and then calls the actual entrypoing `"/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"`